# best way to index a text consist of multilingual word in elasticsearch

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch, multilingual

I'm new to elasticsearch.The doc on official site just say the basic and do not contain specific example.Due to it is a little disorganized as my view, I can't figure out how to get start to achieve my purpose.

I have crawl a lot of torrents, they are published by many different language.
I see there is analysis in elasticsearch to deal with input text, but I don't understand the work flow. elasticsearch do not use all analyzers to process input data as I try.
It seems I should appoint a analyzer to process a text.
Such as a text :`no game no life  游戏人生  ノーゲーム・ノーライフ`, it contain three language.How can I know which three analyzers I have to use?And it also too heavy to use all analyzer to process this text.
I have seen a article [Three Principles for Multilingal Indexing in Elasticsearch](http://gibrown.wordpress.com/2013/05/01/three-principles-for-multilingal-indexing-in-elasticsearch/) talk about this.However I am a beginner and non-native English speaker, it is hard to understand without a example.

Please give me some guide.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably create two fields (or multiple for number of expected languages) and apply different analyzers (language dependent) to each of them. Then when you search you would search both fields.